# Convert string to array, strcpy don't work

Tags: c++, arrays, string, visual-studio-2013, strcpy

i tryed to use this algorithm to convert a string to an array.
the problem is this: strcpy don't work.

i tried also:
strcpy_s
strncpy
memcpy --> with this function my array can print only the 1st word ( dunno why )...

```
string tmp;
getline(cin, tmp);
char* messaggio = new char[tmp.size()];
ZeroMemory(messaggio, tmp.size());
strcpy(messaggio, tmp.c_str());

tmp.resize(NULL);
```

i use Visual Studio 2013...
when i try to use strcpy i have a strange error: C4996 may be unsafe.
if i try with strcpy_s is the same, same with strncpy...

Comment: you have mentioned about print only 1st word and 2nd is C4996 compilation error. Are you getting compilation error or you are getting unexpected run time output. Both are different problem.

Comment: For compilation error(C4496) you read from here about how to disable it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttcz0bys.aspx

Comment: @tmp Is it an error, or just a warning?

Comment: in compile time i see this error. in another part of my algorithm i had the same error with "itoa" and "itoa_s" funcion, but i solved him changing the parameters... 
the 1st word print was only for "memcpy" for the others function i found only the error C4996.

Comment: Can you use std::string? It has a lot more functionality and would make this much easier.

Comment: tryed with "std::string" ( declared: {std::string tmp}) same error :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]

thx at all, expecially to "Vlad from Moscow" :3

```
std::string tmp;
        tmp.resize(0);
        std::getline(std::cin, tmp);
        char* messaggio = new char[tmp.size()+1];

        strcpy_s(messaggio, tmp.size()+1, tmp.c_str());

        send(ConnectSocket, messaggio, tmp.size()+1, NULL); //Send 2

        tmp.resize(0);
        delete messaggio;
```

Answer (score 2):

One problem in your code, is that `string::size` gives you the number of characters excluding the null termination. So `messagio` does not have enough room for a nul-terminated string, and `strcpy` will try to write beyond its bounds.

As for the warning, it is because `strcpy` makes it very easy to go out of bounds. If the length of the source string is greater than that of the destination buffer, you get undefined behaviour. The suggested alternatives give you means to protect yourself from that (but are  not 100% fool-proof).

If what you want is an array-like object containing the characters of the string, then the idiomatic way to do this is to use a vector:

```
std::vector<char> messagio(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
```

If you really want a character string, then just use `std::string`.

Comment: Another is that the code will inevitably leak memory.  He should be using `std::vector<char>` for his C style string.

Comment: thx for ur help, but my prob is not the string but the array...
infact i need to put string,vector,list... into an array, not the reverse...

Comment: @user3464250 But why do you have to do that? It isn't clear from your question, so it could be that you don't actually need it.

Comment: i need it... i pref to use string and dynamic functions but this program is using winsocket2 functions... infact i will use this function after this conversion: ""send(ConnectSocket, messaggio, tmp.size(), NULL);"" send need a char pointer but i need to send a message so i need a pointer to an array... also i need to send a message with "space"... for example now i send this "Hi There!"... with only an array my cout is: "Hi" and "There!" not "Hi There!"

Comment: @user3464250 What about `send(ConnectSocket, tmp.c_str(), tmp.size(), NULL);`?

Comment: i need to use "send" func to send the message (messaggio) at the server... the problem is that send need a pointer to a char and i can't use string or vector... but i want a good message in cout like <User 1:> Hi there! and not <User 1:> Hi /0 <User 1:> There!

Comment: @user3464250 Try the line I posted above.

Comment: thx! i tryed ur lane and print the 1st word
"Hi There"
<User 1> Hi

Answer (score 0):

The error you got in fact is not an error. It is a warning. Maybe you set on the option of the compiler that forces the compiler to consider all warnings as errors.

Your code has a bug. The size of the allocated array shall be one greater than the size of the string that to accomodate the terminating zero used by function `std::strcpy`

So you should write

```
std::string tmp;
std::getline( std::cin, tmp );

char* messaggio = new char[tmp.size() + 1];
std::strcpy( messaggio, tmp.c_str() );
```

Or you could write

```
strcpy_s( messaggio, tmp.size() + 1, tmp.c_str() );
```

though function `strcpy_s` is not a standard C++ function. It is present only in the C Standard.

I am sure you should ignore this warning.

If your compiler supports class `std::dynarray` you could use it instead of the raw pointer.

For example

```
std::dynarray<char> messagio( tmp.size() + 1 );
std::strcpy( messagio.data(), tmp.c_str() );
```

Comment: thank you, but problem still is on...
dynarray is not supported i think... 
anyway i need a pointer cause after i will use a fuction that recive a pointer as parameter.
 for (;;){
  std::string tmp;
  std::getline(std::cin, tmp);
  char* messaggio = new char[tmp.size()+1];
  ZeroMemory(messaggio, tmp.size()+1);
  std::strcpy(messaggio, tmp.c_str());
  send(ConnectSocket, messaggio, tmp.size(), NULL); 
  tmp.resize(NULL);
 }

Comment: I have not understood what problem you are speaking about> And why are you using ZeroMemory when there is no such call in my example? And what value should be used in function send temp.size() or tmp.size() + 1?

Comment: tryed with and without ZeroMemory but still nothing... i also took another project (similar at this) and see if options in the menu was the same... it are! when i go back to home i will see with more attention, but i think options are ok..... also i tryed with tmp.size() and tmp.size()+1 and nothing changed :/:/:/:/

Comment: @user34 I do not understand what "still nothing" means. The code I showed is valid and workable.

Comment: @user3464250 if you mean that the compiler does not allow to use std::strcpy then use std::strncpy or strcpy_s as it suggest.